# Easy way to submit POST data from a hyperlink in Django? Equivalent of Rails' `button_to`?

Tags: django, post, django-templates, django-forms

Is there a quick way to submit (pre-defined) POST data from a hyperlink in a Django template? I've got an 'add this to my favourites' link on page. I'm currently doing this with a GET request, which obviously breaks all kinds of rules.

I could manually build a form and have the link submit it with Javascript. I'm looking for an automatic way to do the same thing, essentially the equivalent of Rails' `button_to`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I can find. Sounds like a good candidate for [a template tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags) and [sharing](http://www.djangosnippets.org/).